# Incompatible / error connecting as MTP device after unlocking and rooting Nexus 4

Tags: rooting, nexus-4, bootloader-lock, mtp

I unlocked and rooted my Nexus 4

- it shows as connected
- it shows in my computer

But when copying a file, it gives me an error stating "device is unavailable or may have been removed"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to replicate the same error on other computers and OSs? If it's just your computer, remove all drivers and related software and then connect your device and add them again.

Otherwise, you can attempt to [ftp to your device](http://support.solidexplorer.pl/responses/using-solid-explorer-to-launch-ftp-server-on-an-android-devicehttp://support.solidexplorer.pl/responses/using-solid-explorer-to-launch-ftp-server-on-an-android-device) using [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer&hl=en). It does not require a cable; you'd be able to transfer files over WiFi (albeit a little slower).